# Dismiss YTPlayerView() and return to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, youtubeplayer

I have a UITableView embedded inside of my container view which is being modally presented over current context. The videos load fine but there is no way for me to simply dismiss the video and return back to my UITableView. I would like the option for the video to be able to be closed and simply return to the original tableView.

[image: TableView]
[image: videoLoaded]

```
class MotivationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, YTPlayerViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(playerView)
    playerView.delegate = self

    search()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    print(dataArray)
    tableView.register(YouTubeTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(titleLabel)

    containerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 200, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 200, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    tableView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left:         containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    titleLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: containerView.topAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! YouTubeTableCell

    let item = titlesArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = item
    let imageURL = URL(string: thumbnailArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.thumbnailImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let item = videoID[indexPath.row]
    view.addSubview(playerView)
    playerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    playerView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let playerVars = ["playsinline": 1] // 0: will play video in fullscreen
    self.playerView.load(withVideoId: item, playerVars: playerVars)
  }

func dismiss() {

    self.playerView.removeFromSuperview()

  }

}
```

Comment: ok, so how you want to do that?

Comment: i think swiping down on the video will be ideal, or if the video is full screen pressing the x button on the video.

Comment: please show the code of your dismiss action

Comment: I was using this one i added on previous views if the background of container view was touched to return home. But I am not sure where I would add it for playerView to dismiss.

Comment: @soRazor - just add the code of `self.view.removefromSuperView(playerView)` in inside the dismiss action and hide this one also `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: but where would I add dismiss() to

Comment: Why did you add playerView to view in viewDidLoad and again in tableview didSelectRowAt ?
I think you should add it at ViewDidload and set hidden = true,
When didselected, set hidden = false and loads the video.
One more thing, when dissmiss remember to stop video

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a close button and constraining it on the top right of my containerView and setting it to hidden once the video was dismissed.

```
  @objc func dismissVideo() {
    self.playerView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.isHidden = true

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let item = videoID[indexPath.row]
    view.addSubview(playerView)
     playerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    playerView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let playerVars = ["playsinline": 1] // 0: will play video in fullscreen
    self.playerView.load(withVideoId: item, playerVars: playerVars)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissVideo), for: .touchUpInside)
    closeButton.isHidden = false
}
```